# Каким способом решить эту задачу?

Tags: javascript

В метод даю массив который состоит из нечетных(четных) чисел, но 1 из
чисел четный(нечетный) в каждом массиве. Метод должен
вернуть единственное четное(нечетное) число заданного массива
соответственно. Я всякие методы массива использовала чтобы решить
задачу. Но не получилось.

**P.S. Пожалуйста не пишите готовое решение,
просто дайте подсказку чтоб сама смогла решить.**

```js
function Outlier(){
 
  this.method=function(arr)
  {
    
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     
   
    if(arr[i]%2==0){
     return arr[i]%2!=0; //Проблема больше всего вот здесь
    }
     
   if(arr[i]%2!=0){
     return arr[i]%2==0; //Проблема .... И здесь
    }

  }

  } }
  
let array1=[11, 3, 5, 9, 29, 4];
let array2=[2, 4, 6, 180, 7];

let outlier=new Outlier();

let out=outlier.method(array1);
//  outlier.method(array2);
console.log(out);
```

**Version 2**

```js
function Outlier(){
 
  this.method=function (arr)
  {
    
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     
   
  

  if(arr[0]%2==0&&arr[1]%2==0||arr[2]%2==0)
  return "even"

  if(arr[0]%2!=0&&arr[1]%2!=0||arr[2]%2!=0)
  return "odd"

  }  
  
  } }
  
let array1=[3, 4, 5, 9, 29];
 let array2=[7, 2, 4, 6, 180];


let outlier=new Outlier();

let out=outlier.method(array1);
let out1= outlier.method(array2);
console.log(out); //odd
console.log(out1); //even
```

> В этом let array2=[7, 2, 4, 6, 180]; массиве  вне зависимости где находится нечетный элемент 
>   if(arr[0]%2==0&&arr[1]%2==0||arr[2]%2==0)
>         return "even" правильно работает
>
> А в этом let array1=[3, 4, 5, 9, 29]; массиве когда четный элемент имеет индекс [2] 
>    if(arr[0]%2!=0&&arr[1]%2!=0||arr[2]%2!=0)
>         return "odd" неправильно работает
>   **Почему так?**

**Version 3 Проверка - что есть минимум 3 элемента и что нет строк**. Там конечно не проверка на содержание любой строки(только заданной).

```js
function Outlier(){
    this.method=function(arr) {
      if(arr.length>=3&&arr.join(" ").search(/ab*c/)==-1){
        let reminder = (arr[0]+arr[1])%2==1 ? 1-arr[2]%2 : 1-arr[0]%2;
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){        
            if(arr[i]%2==reminder){
                return arr[i];
            }
        }
     }
    else{
      return `Array's length <3 or Array has the string(s). 
 Please add number(s) to the array or delete the string(s)`;
    }
    }
}

let array1=[11, 3, 5,"cbbabbbbcdebc,", 9, 29, 4];
let array2=[2, 4, 6, 180, 7, 20];
let outlier=new Outlier();
let out=outlier.method(array1);
console.log(out);
out=outlier.method(array2);
console.log(out);
```

**Version 4  Проверка каждого элемента массива - что нет строк и что есть минимум 3 элемента в массиве**

```js
function Outlier(){
    this.method=function(arr) {
 
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if(arr.length>=3&&arr.join(" ").search(/ab*c/)==-1)    {

     let reminder = (arr[0]+arr[1])%2==1 ? 1-arr[2]%2 : 1-arr[0]%2;
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){  
  
            if(arr[i]%2==reminder){
                return arr[i];
            }
        }
            
          }  

          else{
            return `Array's length <3 or Array has the string(s). 
 Please add number(s) to the array or delete the string(s)`;

          }
  }
     
     }
    
    }


let array1=[11, 3, 5,"cbbabbbbcdebc,", 9, 29,   4];
let array2=[2, 4, 6, 180, 7, 20];
let outlier=new Outlier();
let out=outlier.method(array1);
console.log(out);
out=outlier.method(array2);
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Сначала надо определить, чёт или нечёт искать. Это делается простым сканированием первых 3 элементов (если чётность первых двух совпадает, то третий уже можно и не сканировать). Получив критерий для поиска, одним проходом получаем нужный элемент. Такой подход при его кажущейся неоптимальности намного проще, чем чистый однопроходник.

Comment: дак зачем вы выходите то из цикла после проверки?  заведите два массива для четных и нечетных, и распихивайте туда значения эти, выведите потом тот где одно значение.

Comment: @Akina Щас анализирую ваш ответ. Я выше вставила новый код. Можете плиз проверить почему там так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Outlier(){
    this.method=function(arr) {
        let reminder = (arr[0]+arr[1])%2==1 ? 1-arr[2]%2 : 1-arr[0]%2;
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){        
            if(arr[i]%2==reminder){
                return arr[i];
            }
        }
    } 
}

let array1=[11, 3, 5, 9, 29, 4];
let array2=[2, 4, 6, 180, 7, 20];
let outlier=new Outlier();
let out=outlier.method(array1);
console.log(out);
out=outlier.method(array2);
console.log(out);
```

`let reminder = (arr[0]+arr[1])%2==1 ? 1-arr[2]%2 : 1-arr[0]%2;` определяет, какой остаток будем искать. Если сумма первых двух нечётна, то требуемый элемент среди них, и нужная чётность не такая, как у третьего элемента. А если чётна, то их чётность одинакова и не такая, как нужна, получаем требуемую чётность не такую, как у первого элемента. Ну а остальное - очевидно.

По-хорошему, надо добавить ещё проверок - что есть минимум 3 элемента, что нет строк или ещё какой дряни...

Comment: все понятно, спасибо. <надо добавить ещё проверок - что есть минимум 3 элемента, что нет строк>  Я добавила в ваш код. Код вы можете увидеть выше. Пожалуйста посмотрите вы такую проверку имели ввиду. P.S. Там с регулярными выражениями у меня неправильно(пока), ибо поверхностно анализировала эту тему.

Comment: @devafina *вы такую проверку имели ввиду* Нет, конечно, какое-нибудь `arr[n] = "_-=#=-_"` ТАКУЮ проверку пролетит не глядя. Следует КАЖДЫЙ элемент массива в КАЖДОЙ операции (вернее, перед ней - так что разумнее сделать это отдельным циклом) проверять на число. Хотя дело Ваше - может, оно и не надо, если валидность массива гарантирована в точке вызова?

Comment: я бы еще учел ситуацию, когда есть одновременно как минимум 2 четных и 2 нечетных числа (не соответствие условию задачи).

Comment: @Akina, понятно. Я изменила код и добавила выше. Надеюсь это имели ввиду.

Comment: @Алексей Обухов Интересно, надо подумать алгоритм.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Собственно ВСЕ передаваемые параметры необходимо проверять на корректность перед выполнением требуемых операций. С другой стороны, отсутствие такой проверки просто слегка трансформирует саму задачу, но не влияет на код выполнения основной функции. А сама проверка потребует дополнительного прохода по всему массиву... я бы такое несоответствие проигнорировал, а в документации написал, что надо лучше готовить исходные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать метод массива .some();
Он возвращает true, при первом совпадении с заданным условием.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arr[i]%2==0){
 return arr[i]%2!=0; //Проблема больше всего вот здесь
}

if(arr[i]%2!=0){
 return arr[i]%2==0; //Проблема .... И здесь
}
```

мне (и Вам тоже) не нранятся эти строчки. для начала приведите их к человеческому языку:

```
var val = arr[i];
if (chetnoe(val))
  return false;
if (!chetnoe(val))
  return false;
```

это неверный алгоритм. он всегда возращает false. но он позволяет сделать шаг к правильному.

у вас уже есть какой-то код, вспомогательные функции и вы можете строить алгоритм имея такие "кубики".

подумайте, как бы вы решили свою задачу, имея в арсенале функцию chetnoe (возращает true, если аргумент четный).

попробуйте факт четности обозначить 1, а нечетности -1. что потом можно сделать с этими числами?

Comment: если вам написание `chetnoe` нравится и более понятно чем `x%2==0`, то все печально, имхо.

Comment: согласен, можно оставить x%2==0. тут я переборщил с человечностью. хотел обратить внимание человека на достаточно простой прием: если что-то не получается сделать в один метод (строчку кода), то можно попробовать написать вспомогательные методы. будет больше кода, но понятнее.